# Execute permission for SP_SEND_MAIL not working?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sp-send-dbmail

I humbly ask for your guidance regarding this matter.

I am trying to execute a stored procedure from SQL SERVER. I used it in a VB.NET application.

When using "SA" login in the connection string, I can execute the code no problem, but if not... I receive this error

```
The EXECUTE permission was denied on the object 'sp_send_dbmail', database 'msdb', schema 'dbo'.
```

So, I searched in this site and the others, pointing out to add permissions to the account where the command does not proceed, to DatabaseMailUserRole.

I think I had done that, not using this [method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2008-r2/ms188719(v=sql.105))  though

Here are the screenshots of the things that I did.

[image]
granted execution

[image]

[image]

Below is the command that I would like to run in the stored procedure.

```
                    exec msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail 
                    @profile_name = 'SendSQLMail', 
                    @recipients = 'test@gmail.com', 
                    @blind_copy_recipients ='test2@gmail.com',
                    @subject = 'TESTS', 
                    @body =  "A SOMETHING",
                    @execute_query_database = '[FF]',
                    @body_format = 'text'
```

Please do tell me if you need more details regarding my work

EDIT:

The UserName that I would like to grant access is FF

Comment: @marc_s I dont... Sorry, what I mean is, testing sp_dbsendmail using SA works fine, but not if other logins.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, Please tell me if what I did is wrong or what..

First I read this [artice](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic1694911-2799-1.aspx)

```
GRANT EXECUTE ON object::sp_send_dbmail TO DatabaseMailUserRole
```

I got this code and tried to run it, **nothing** happened, well, the error happened.

Then the most common solution:

```
EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_addrolemember @rolename = 'DatabaseMailUserRole'
    ,@membername = 'ff';
GO
```

Did not work either...

But when I used

```
ALTER DATABASE <mydatabase> SET TRUSTWORTHY ON
```

It worked fine... But, does setting the database to being **TRUSTWORTHY** has its consequences? Please do take note this is just a internal network project.

Answer (score 0):

If it is working for `sa`, only issue I see is permissions. Try adding same permissions for `sa` user to your user for `msdb`. I am adding screenshot for reference.

[image]

Here I have highlighted required permissions in yellow.

For any user make sure `msdb` has `server roles` `public` & `sysadmin` and `User Mapping` is also selected for `msdb` table from which you are trying to execute Stored Procedure.

Comment: I did, I also check DatabaseMailUserRole but it does not work still